# Creating XName.Get In For Each Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, visual-studio-2010

I have a LINQ Statement. It searches an XML file. (See example below) There are certain nodes that are required to have information in them. (Not empty) The LINQ Statement returns the transactions that have nodes which are empty, because these are required.

**XML File Example:**

```
<OnlineBanking>
  <Transactions>
    <Txn>
      <UserName>John Smith</UserName>
      <CustomerStreet>123 Main</CustomerStreet>
      <CustomerStreet2></CustomerStreet2>
      <CustomerCity>New York</CustomerCity>
      <CustomerState>NY</CustomerState>
      <CustomerZip>12345</CustomerZip>
    </Txn>
  </Transactions>
</OnlineBanking>
```

**LINQ Statement:**

```
//Start LINQ statement
var transactionList =
    from transactions in root.Elements(XName.Get("Transactions")).Elements().AsEnumerable()
    where transactions.Elements().Any
       (
          el =>
          String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Value) &&
          elementsThatCannotBeEmpty.Contains(el.Name)
       )
    select transactions;
```

**My Question:**

I have the required fields (ie. CustomerStreet, CustomerCity, etc) in a database table. Below I have hard coded the XName's that are required.  However, I want this to be dynamic from the database.

```
var elementsThatCannotBeEmpty = new HashSet<XName>
{
   XName.Get("CustomerStreet"),
   XName.Get("CustomerCity"),
   XName.Get("CustomerState"),
   XName.Get("CustomerZip")
};
```

Here is how I am retrieving the fields that are required from the database:

```
List<Setting> settingList = SettingsGateway.SelectBySettingType("VerifyField");
foreach (Setting SettingValue in settingList)
{
    string strSettingType = setting.SettingType;
}
```

How do I take my database result loop and dynamically add XName.Get values?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to check whether `Any()` of the strings in `settingList` are empty:

```
if (settingList.Any(
        name => String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element(name).Value)
    )
```

There is an implicit conversion from `string` to `XName`, so you don't actually need to call `XName.Get`.
If you want to, though, you could write `el.Element(XName.Get(name))`

Comment: Where would I add this in my current LINQ statement? I am confused on how to take the code you provided and put it into mine... thanks.

Comment: Probably in your `where` clause.

Comment: Here is my where clause, but i get an error:

`where transactions.Elements().Any
(
el =>
settingList.Any(name => String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element(name).Value))
)`

Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(System.Xml.Linq.XName)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `name` isn't a string.  Try `name.SettingType`

Comment: `where transactions.Elements().Any
(
  el =>
  settingList.Any(
   name => String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Element(name.SettingValue).Value)
   ) 
  )`
<br/>
Everything looks good, but after adding the code after the "el =>" I run the LINQ statement and nothing returns back...

Comment: Nothing is coming up when I put in the above code... do I put it inside the `where transactions.Elements().Any()` as I have above? I am confused and would greatly appreciate your help, or anyone elses. Thanks again.